# How to get new pandas dataframe with certain columns and rows depending on list elements?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have such a list:

```
l = ['A','B']
```

And such a dataframe `df`

```
Name x y
A 1 2
B 2 1
C 2 2
```

I now want to get a new dataframe where only the entries for Name and x which are included in `l` are kept.

`new_df` should look like this:

```
Name x
A 1
B 2
```

I was playing around with `isin` but did not solve this problem.

Comment: `I was playing around with isin but did not solve this problem.` Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
new_df = df.loc[df.Name.isin(l), ["Name", "x"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```py
# assuming Name is the index
new_df = df[df.index.isin(l)]
# if you only want column x
new_df = df.loc[df.index.isin(l), "x"]
```

simple as that

Comment: Thanks a lot! I accepeted the other answer as correct, since `Name` was not my index.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['A','B']

def make_empty(row):
    print(row)
    for idx, value in enumerate(row):
        row[idx] = value if value in l else ''
    return row

df_new = df[df['Name'].isin(l) | df['x'].isin(l)][['Name','x']]
df_new.apply(lambda row: make_empty(row)

Output:
    Name x
0    A  
1    B
```

Comment: If check expected ouput OP dont need empty `x`

Comment: Now I feel silly. Made it too complicated unnecessarily.